# Angular ngx-datable conditional prop?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I have an ngx-datatable and I'm trying to get a column value from two different objects according to a condition.

I tried adding the condition in the prop field, but that doesn't work.

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Price" prop="counters ? counters[counterBidsNo - 1].price : price">
    <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{ value }} {{ offer?.payment.currency }}
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Any way to achieve this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use brackets around `prop` you will bind the normal text to it. How ever, if you wrap it with brackets `[prop]` you will bind the object to it. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property)

So your solution would be

```
[prop]="counters ? counters[counterBidsNo - 1].price : price"
```